# SMPP BIND ERROR: 0x0000000D in EasySMPP

Tags: c#, .net, api, smpp

I am implementing the [SMPP](http://www.tele2.lt/files/SMPP_protocol_v3_4.pdf) client using [EasySMPP](http://tnt64.blogspot.com/search/label/SMPP) for .NET

The application is compiling fine but there was no successful outcome and I am getting this weird error

```
SMPP BIND ERROR: 0x0000000D
```

What can be done for this, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code of 0x0000000D is unfortunately a rather generic "Bind Failed".

To find out what the error codes mean check section 5.1.3, command_status, of the SMPP specification you linked to.

Common causes for getting a "Bind Failed" response are:

- Your supplier only allows certain IP addresses to connect
- Trying to connect to wrong hostname/port combination
- Wrong username/password

To troubleshoot, you could try running Wireshark on your client and take a look at the SMPP PDUs being passed backwards and forwards, if you post the capture on here I'm happy to take a look.  Or you could give your supplier a call, they may be able to see something helpful in their server logs.

Comment: Thanks for info... I will check as you said and revert with the response very soon....

Comment: accepted your specially for wire shark... I had checked my smpp configuration with a trial smpp client software... And checked the the raw data with the client software that we are developing...

Comment: And it helped me a lot... I was testing with invalid ph number format.. i.e added + in the ph number... :D